# Does the postponed tax-filing deadline affect Roth IRA contribution deadline?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira, irs

Since Mnuchin has pushed back the filing deadline to July 15th this year ([IRS announcement](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/tax-day-now-july-15-treasury-irs-extend-filing-deadline-and-federal-tax-payments-regardless-of-amount-owed) and [Notice 2020-18](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/n-20-18.pdf)), does that also push back the deadline to contribute to a Roth IRA?

[irs.gov](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/traditional-and-roth-iras) says this about the Roth IRA contribution deadline:

> Your tax return filing deadline (not including extensions). For example, you can make 2019 IRA contributions until April 15, 2020.

But I don't think what Mnuchin did was extend the deadline for everyone, I think he changed the actual date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the deadline for making contributions to Traditional IRA and Roth IRA for 2019 is now July 15, 2020. See [this IRS FAQ](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/filing-and-payment-deadlines-questions-and-answers):

> Q17. Does this relief provide me more time to contribute money to my
>   IRA for 2019?
>
> A17. Yes. Contributions can be made to your IRA, for a particular
>   year, at any time during the year or by the due date for filing your
>   return for that year. Because the due date for filing Federal income
>   tax returns has been postponed to July 15, the deadline for making
>   contributions to your IRA for 2019 is also extended to July 15, 2020.